# How can I get my SKNodes in different file from the gamescene swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I couldn't find anything on having SKNodes in seperate files from the gamescene.swift. I tried writing this in a new class swift file but did not seem to work. I had to make a function but I did not know how to call it in my gamescene.

```
let testLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "AppleSDGothicNeo-Medium")
    testLabel.text = "TEST"
    testLabel.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX, y: 300)
    testLabel.fontSize = 90
    testLabel.color = SKColor.blue
    testLabel.horizontalAlignmentMode = SKLabelHorizontalAlignmentMode.center
```

I'm trying to make this in another swift file and only use the testlabel in my gamescene.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by having an `SKNode` in a separate file?

Comment: Cleaner files only

Comment: @MarkBrownsword I think the OP is asking how to subclass `SKNodes` in Swift, not sure though :)

Comment: @NSDawg I thought so too, but doesn't seem much point in doing that unless there is a reason like adding extra functionality.

Comment: make a struct with static funcs that return nodes; you can make one node and use it in all of your projects / scenes.

Comment: @Fluidity A Struct and static function would work, but I would discourage it as a goto solution because the code ends up with dependencies that are not immediately obvious. A better approach I think, is to use extensions for sharing logic between scenes.

Comment: @MarkBrownsword an extension to what, an SKScene? Or are you saying have the gamescenes inherit from the utility class?

Comment: An extension on SKScene would be a starting point, or you could add a protocol e.g. `sceneUtilities` to the scene and create an extension for the protocol. Swift enables these options to be explored!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than creating a new file, you could consider creating a property for your label inside the GameScene.swift file. This lets you add the label to the scene by calling `self.testLabel`.

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    lazy var testLabel: SKLabelNode! = {
        let testLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "AppleSDGothicNeo-Medium")
        testLabel.text = "TEST"
        testLabel.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX, y: 300)
        testLabel.fontSize = 90
        testLabel.color = SKColor.blue
        testLabel.horizontalAlignmentMode = SKLabelHorizontalAlignmentMode.center

        return testLabel
    }()

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        self.addChild(self.testLabel)
    }
}
```

It doesn't really make sense to create a new file, unless you want to create a custom `SKLabelNode` with some extended functionality.

Another approach could be to create a function that creates a label from input parameters.

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    func makeTestLabel(text: String, position: CGPoint) -> SKLabelNode {
        let testLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "AppleSDGothicNeo-Medium")
        testLabel.text = text
        testLabel.position = position
        testLabel.fontSize = 90
        testLabel.color = SKColor.blue
        testLabel.horizontalAlignmentMode = SKLabelHorizontalAlignmentMode.center

        return testLabel
    }

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        self.addChild(self.makeTestLabel(text: "Test1", position: CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX, y: 300)))
        self.addChild(self.makeTestLabel(text: "Test2", position: CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX, y: 400)))
    }
}
```

Another option, if you want to share this between scenes would be to create an extension on `SKScene` and move the `makeTestLabel` function. How it is used remains the same. This gives flexibility to reuse logic between scenes and answers your original question!

```
// SKScene+Extensions.swift
import SpriteKit
extension SKScene {
    func makeTestLabel(text: String, position: CGPoint) -> SKLabelNode {
        let testLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "AppleSDGothicNeo-Medium")
        testLabel.text = text
        testLabel.position = position
        testLabel.fontSize = 90
        testLabel.color = SKColor.blue
        testLabel.horizontalAlignmentMode = SKLabelHorizontalAlignmentMode.center

        return testLabel
    }
}

// GameScene.swift
class GameScene: SKScene {
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        self.addChild(self.makeTestLabel(text: "Test1", position: CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX, y: 300)))
        self.addChild(self.makeTestLabel(text: "Test2", position: CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX, y: 400)))
    }
}
```

Comment: okay makes sense i was just wondering because if you have over 10 nodes it gets messy

Comment: Then you could make a function to create the labels, that would reduce the duplication if you need to create many labels.

Comment: I updated the example again to show using an extension to move logic into separate files.